# Disable movement of a javafx alert

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, alert

I have a problem with my "Do you want to quit" interface.

As of today I can move the alert box where I want, which I would like to change - preferably fixating the alert in a set position (in the middle of the screen).

The problem with this alert being able to move around is that on setups with more than one screen you could move it wherever you would like (out of the game interface f.e.).

```
    Button btExit = new Button("Exit Game");
    btExit.setMinWidth(100);
    buttonGrid.add(btExit, 0, 5);
    btExit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("");
            alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
            alert.setHeaderText("Quit Game");
            alert.setContentText("Are you sure?");

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                System.exit(1);
            }else 
            {
                alert.close();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What has changed, that the `Alert` dialog can now be moved, if it could not before?

Comment: And you want your alert box to remain within the limits of your initial window?

Comment: The alert dialog was able to be moved before too, the problem being I want it to stay where it gets visible and it should not be movable by the user too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent the user from moving the dialog, simply set the style to `UNDECORATED` which removes the window border the user could use to move around the alert (as well as the x-button, but the user has a alternative way of closing the dialog):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Show alert");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
        alert.setHeaderText("Quit Game");
        alert.setContentText("Are you sure?");

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.orElse(null) == ButtonType.OK) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Some other modifications I did here:

- Replace

  ```
  System.exit(1);
  ```

  with

  ```
  Platform.exit();
  ```

  To shut down the application more gracefully. After all a status code of `1` indicates **abnormal termination**.
- Remove

  ```
  else 
  {
      alert.close();
  }
  ```

  this is never necessary, since `showAndWait` only returns after the `Alert` is closed anyways...
- Used

  ```
  result.orElse(null)
  ```

  to retrieve the value without an error, even if the `Optional` is empty (not 100% sure this can happen in this case, but it does not hurt to do it like this).